Getting this error 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future
void main() {
  late ApiManager apiManager;
  late MockHTTPClient mockHTTPClient;

  setUp(() {
    mockHTTPClient = MockHTTPClient();
    apiManager = ApiManager(mockHTTPClient);
  });
 test(
        'given UserRepository class when getUser function is called and status code is 200 then a usermodel should be returned',
        () async {
          // Arrange
          const mockResponse = '{"status": "200"}';
          String url = "url";
          when(() {
            return mockHTTPClient.post(Uri.parse(url));
          }).thenAnswer((invocation) => Future.delayed(Durations.short2,() => Response(mockResponse, 200),), );
          // Act
          final user = await apiManager.userLoginApi();
          // Assert
          expect(isuserExist, isA<Data()>());
        },
      );


Future<Data> userLoginApi({String? email, String? password}) async {
    final response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse('url'),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, String> body = {
        "email": email.toString(),
        "password": password.toString()
      };
      return Data.fromJson(body);
    }
    throw Exception('Some Error Occurred');
  }

Getting this error 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future.. Also, what should i pass in the body. It's a user login api which includes email and pass. Since its a test case i cant pass the user credentials.

Note that when using mocks, the arguments to stubbed functions must match exactly.  For example, if the post method is called with different request headers, your mock will not be called.  If you're using package:http, it's usually a lot more straightforward to use its MockClient class instead of trying to mock it yourself.

try changing these :
  when(() => mockHTTPClient.post(Uri.parse(url)))
      .thenAnswer((_) async => Response(mockResponse, 200));

  // Act
  final user = await apiManager.userLoginApi(email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test');
 //pass mock email and password here to the userLoginApi method.

and also:
Future<Data> userLoginApi({String? email, String? password}) async {
  final response = await client.post(
    Uri.parse('url'),
    body: {
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
    return Data.fromJson(body);  // Adjust this according to your Data model
  }

  throw Exception('Some Error Occurred');
}

and lets see the results.
let me know if it was helpful.

It's still throwing the same error  type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future'
